# Select value loaded with jQuery load function doesn´t appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a select whose values are loaded with load function jQuery:

Html:

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect"></select>
```

Script jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myselect").load('ajax.php?op=selectYESNO&id=YES');
});
```

File ajax.php with case:

```
    case 'selectYESNO':            
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>
              <option value="YES">YES</option>
              <option value="NO">NO</option>';        
    break;
```

Well, my problem is that although **the select is set on the form** (it takes value YES), if I see its value I get undefined value or null:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myselect").load('ajax.php?op=selectYESNO&id=YES');

    alert($("#myselect option:selected").val());  => undefined
    alert($("#myselect").val());                  => null
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you putting the code to display the selection? Can you show the rest of the code as that will affect it.

Comment: Are you getting the `val()` *after* the `load()` has completed? You need to make sure the async request has completed and the HTML has been added to the `select`.

Comment: Rory McCrossan I think this may be the solution, how I manage the event is completed? Could I force it?

Comment: `$("#myselect").load('ajax.php?op=selectYESNO&id=YES', function(){ $("#myselect").val() });` Use load complete function.

Comment: still does not work, I even tried to assign the value before the alert and does not work: $("#myselect").val('YES'); The result is the same, undefined or null @RejithRKrishnan

Comment: Rory McCrossan I think this may be the solution, how I manage the event is completed? Could I force it? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Use the callback handler of `load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: this can be done with `$.ajax()`

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye I have already completed the code something, my problem is that when I want to get the value has not yet been completed the load, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the data was loaded into the page then try this
`alert( $(document).find("#myselect option:selected").val() );`

instead of :
`alert($("#myselect option:selected").val());`